# Twitter OAuth2 token revoking returns 401 error saying "Client application is not permitted to to invalidate this token."

Tags: twitter, oauth-2.0, axios, twitter-oauth

I can obtain the OAuth2 token, but can't revoke it.

Reproducing the error:

```
let token_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
let revoke_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/invalidate_token"
let auth = {
    username: CLIENT_API_KEY,
    password: CLIENT_API_SECRET_KEY
}
axios.post(token_url, "grant_type=client_credentials", { auth })
.then( response => {
    let access_token = response.data["access_token"]
    axios.post(revoke_url, `access_token=${access_token}`, { auth })
    .then( response => {
        console.log("REVOKE SUCCESS")
        console.log(response)
    })
    .catch( e=> {
        console.log("Failed to revoke")
        console.log(e.response.data)
    })
})
```

then I get

```
Failed to revoke
{ errors:
   [ { code: 348,
       message:
        'Client application is not permitted to to invalidate this token.' } ] }
```

Tried googling but nothing came out of the code 348 and the message. The http error code is `401 (unauthorized)`.

I will never be able to revoke my OAuth2 token. Help.

Comment: Were you able to find an answer for this?

Comment: @RandikaVishman I posted the question on [this](https://twittercommunity.com/t/oauth2-invalidate-token-not-working-with-sorry-that-page-does-not-exist-code-34-error/120646) and [this](https://twittercommunity.com/t/accesstoken-accesstokensecret/121637) post. On the last post, "andypiper" says "We are working on it and aware of it, but an infrastructure change means that this has not been prioritised. I cannot offer timeline right now."